# PayPal Missing Credential - TransactionSearch(Classic API)

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to call TransactionSearch. But I got exception **Missing credentials Exception** 
[image]
here is my code

```html
TransactionSearchResponseType responseTransactionSearchResponseType = new TransactionSearchResponseType();
TransactionSearchReq requestTransactionSearch = new TransactionSearchReq();
TransactionSearchRequestType transactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType("2012-12-25T00:00:00+0530");
requestTransactionSearch.TransactionSearchRequest = transactionSearchRequest;

Dictionary<string, string> paypalConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
paypalConfig.Add("apiUsername", "userName");
paypalConfig.Add("apiPassword", "passowrd");
paypalConfig.Add("apiSignature", "Signature");
paypalConfig.Add("appid", "appID");
paypalConfig.Add("ipn","https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
paypalConfig.Add("url", "https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=");
paypalConfig.Add("endpoint", "https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/");
paypalConfig.Add("mode", "live");

PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(paypalConfig);
responseTransactionSearchResponseType = service.TransactionSearch(requestTransactionSearch);
```

What would be the reason for this ?
Its not an issue with my credential . then what would me the root cause for this ?

help me please
Thank you

Comment: Need to see the actual request getting generated by the class.

Answer (score 1):

The [`CredentialManager`](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/blob/master/Source/SDK/Manager/CredentialManager.cs#L64) in the **PayPal Core SDK** (which the **PayPal Merchant SDK** uses and is where this exception is originating) requires the account details for a Classic app in the config to be preceded by an `account#.` token.  So for a single account, like how you have your code setup, the config details should be specified as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, string> paypalConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
paypalConfig.Add("account1.apiUsername", "userName");
paypalConfig.Add("account1.apiPassword", "passowrd");
paypalConfig.Add("account1.apiSignature", "Signature");
paypalConfig.Add("account1.applicationId", "appID");
paypalConfig.Add("IPNEndpoint","https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
paypalConfig.Add("url", "https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=");
paypalConfig.Add("endpoint", "https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/");
paypalConfig.Add("mode", "live");
```

Subsequent accounts in the config can be added by incrementing the `account#.` token.

Also, the above code has the following two config property names corrected:

- `appid` should be `account#.applicationId`
- `ipn` should be `IPNEndpoint`

More information on the config keys can be found [here](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/blob/master/Source/SDK/BaseConstants.cs).

Comment: thanks for your reply.. working !!! 

Thanks for you reference link too... Appreciate it